# I can't get my desired SQL result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Owners

```
+----+------+------------+
| id | name | birth_year |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 | John |       1970 |
|  2 | Jane |       1980 |
|  3 | Jack |       1990 |
|  4 | Josh |       2000 |
+----+------+------------+
```

Buylog

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id | owner_id |    date    |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 |        1 | 01/01/2016 |
|  2 |        2 | 01/02/2016 |
|  3 |        2 | 01/03/2016 |
|  4 |        1 | 01/04/2016 |
+----+----------+------------+
```

I need to get all the info from Owners table plus the count of buys per owner:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+
| owners.id | owners.name | owners.birth_year | buylog.Count |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+
|         1 | John        |              1970 |            2 |
|         2 | Jane        |              1980 |            2 |
|         3 | Jack        |              1990 |            0 |
|         4 | Josh        |              2000 |            0 |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

I tried the below query, but that returns with error:

```
Select
  o.id,
  o.name,
  o.birth_year,
  Count(b.id) as Count
From
  owners o
Left Outer Join
  buylog b
On
  b.owner_id = o.id
```

Comment: good work on explaining your data and query well. Bad work on not posting your error

Answer (score 5):

The error message should be pretty clear, you are missing a `group by` clause:

```
  Select
  o.id,
  o.name,
  o.birth_year,
  Count(b.id) as Count
From
  owners o
Left Outer Join
  buylog b
On
  b.owner_id = o.id
Group By o.id,
  o.name,
  o.birth_year
```

Comment: So I should include all fields in the GROUP BY clause except the count?

Comment: Yes, when you are using aggregate functions all attributes selected which are not in an aggregate function should be in the group by

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: If this answer provided you with a solution (which I suspect it does) you can accept it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Query by HoneyBadger will do just fine, however this *might* perform better:

```
SELECT o.id
    , o.name
    , o.birth_year
    , COALESCE(b.Count, 0) AS Count
FROM owners o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT owner_id, COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM buylog
    GROUP BY owner_id
    ) AS b
    ON b.owner_id = o.id;
```

It should bring exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.*, 
CASE 
    WHEN temp.Buylog_count IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE temp.Buylog_count
END
FROM Owners o 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT b.owner_id AS oid, COUNT(*) AS Buylog_count
    FROM Buylog b   
    GROUP BY b.owner_id 
)temp ON temp.oid = o.id
```

Comment: If there are no items in `buylog` table for that `owner_id` , `Buylog_count` will be a `NULL`, not `0`. It doesn't meet A/C.

Comment: That, and for the rest it's more or less a copy of @EvaldasBuinauskas's answer

Comment: And as far as copying goes, it's suspicious how much your answer resembles mine here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762276/sql-use-results-of-one-query-as-search-criteria-for-another-query/34762926#comment57279741_34762926

Comment: As I am new user of stackoveflow and not much friendly with the use of it.
I am not getting recent actions before posting my answer.
Need to refresh page before posting.
Extremely sorry for the mistakes. Will take care of it in future.